# How to fix this issue? Cannot open database '' requested by login. the login failed

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am running this command on Nuget and will show web.config for my connection String. This apps is a web and uses Individual User Account, where namespace like AspNet.Identity are used. The error is 'Cannot open database 'eNtsaRegistration" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user'Mandela\Gcobanim".

```
Scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=eNtsaRegistration;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
<add name="eNtsaRegistration" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-eNtsaRegistration-20200304090520.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-eNtsaRegistration-20200304090520;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I had a work around mates, i managed to make this to work. I was calling incorrect database name. See my solution below.

Comment: I think, personally, this question should be deleted- it was a problem caused by a simple typo that would have taken a long time, and it's unlikely to help future visitors to the question as the only real advice that seems to come out of it is "make  sure your connection string is correct"

Comment: @CaiusJard do you have privilege to delete it? If yes, please do. It's so generic and even the answer won't help anyone.

Comment: @JerdineSabio I can only closevote for reason of "caused by a typo and unlikely to be useful" - the original author can delete, or a moderator can (but they have more important things to do)

Answer (score -1):

Scaffold-DBContext "Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=aspnet-eNtsaRegistration-20200304090520;Integrated Security=True" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models